# What I did is right way to attach inline assembly in c?

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly

What I'm trying to do is optimizing compiling `*.c` file to `*.s` file and getting assembly code from `*.s` file and replace original code with these assembly code in`test.c` file.
Belows are what I did.

Left image is `test.c` and right one is `test.s` which is generated by `gcc -S -O3 test.c`
[image]

So, I copy code in the blue box and attach it in `test.c` code like below.
[image]

But when I'm trying to compile it `gcc -o test test.c`, it occurs error :

```
Error : invalid operands (*ABS* and .text sections) for '<'
```

This error is caused by `"jmpq 400630 <quick_sort>\n\t"` 
What should I do? Thanks.

p.s sorry for no uploading the code. I think that uploading the capture image is more clear than just uploading code. Please understand :)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but it looks like you are missing basic understanding of assembly, let alone inline assembly. I don't think we can teach you that here.

Comment: The assembly on the right side of your first image is taken from the assembly generated as a result of compiling the code in your second image, not the code on the left of the first image. You can tell the because the assembly code on the right has has "#APP" and "#NO_APP" that indicate where inline assembly was included in the assembly file on the right. Instead the `jmpq 400630 <quick_sort>` line in your inline assembly statement shows that you took it from a disassembled executable and not from a '.s' file generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything in assembly listings is actually real and valid in compiler´s inline assembly. It doesn't have to work both ways.

`jmpq` is a relative jump followed by a carefully calculated immediate. It's almost impossible for you to access compiler´s labels using inline assembly, and if ever, why would one do that? Compiler knows the best what is the most optimized way to do something, except for some cases, and copying already optimized output wouldn't be any more optimal than its optimization itself.